# AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) Not Generating Average

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, android-studio, create-view

In my App. I have a series of for tables.

- League
- Bowler
- Series
- Game

By the time a bowler enters in his/her scores the id's might look something like this;

- League id = 2
- Bowler id = 1
- Series id = 1
- Game id's = 1,2,3

In my Games table I am recording the scores for each game played (i.e. 1,2,3).  I want to be able to generate an Average Score for a series (i.e. 1).

I know that this can be done with

```
CREATE VIEW AVERAGE_SCORE AS SELECT AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) FROMFROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " = '" + seriesId + "'" + " ORDER BY " +
        Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";
```

I have managed to get a value to appear in logcat using the following code:

```
public int getSeriesAverage(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId)
    {
        int total = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS AVERAGE_SCORE AS SELECT AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) FROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " = '" + seriesId + "'" + " ORDER BY " +
                Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            total = cursor.getInt(0);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        //Close Database Connection
        database.close();
        Log.d("GET AVERAGE FROM SQL","Average = >>>>" + total + "<<<<");
        return total;
    }
```

However it does not appear to be generating an average value.  In my database I have three scores Game 1 = 222, Game 2 = 300, Game 3 = 200.  The average should be 240.  But Log.d shows it as 0.

```
07-24 19:58:53.385 7287-7287/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GET AVERAGE FROM SQL: Average = >>>>0<<<<
```

What am I doing wrong, any assistance would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Changed Code:

```
public int getSeriesAverage(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId)
    {
        int total = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) FROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " = '" + seriesId + "'", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            total = cursor.getInt(0);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        //Close Database Connection
        database.close();
        Log.d("GET AVERAGE FROM SQL","Average = >>>>" + total + "<<<<");
        return total;
    }
```

Series Class:

```
public class Series {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Series";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID = "league_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_BOWLER_ID = "bowler_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE = "average";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

    private int id;
    private String league_id;
    private String bowler_id;
    private String name;
    private String average;
    private String timestamp;


    // Create table SQL query
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE + " TEXT,"
                    + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                    + ")";

    public Series() {
    }

    public Series(int id, String league_id, String bowler_id, String name, String average, String timestamp) {
        this.id = id;
        this.league_id = league_id;
        this.bowler_id = bowler_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.average = average;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLeagueId() {return league_id;}

    public String getBowlerId() {return bowler_id;}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(String average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLeagueId(String league_id) {
        this.league_id = league_id;
    }

    public void setBowlerId(String bowler_id) {
        this.bowler_id = bowler_id;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Updated Method:

```
 public int getSeriesAverage(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId)
    {
        int total = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT AVG(" + Game.COLUMN_SCORE + ") FROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " = '" + seriesId + "'", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
            total = cursor.getInt(0);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        //Close Database Connection
        database.close();
        Log.d("GET AVERAGE FROM SQL","Average = >>>>" + total + "<<<<");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE,Series.getAverage());
        Log.d("GET AVERAGE FROM SQL","Average = >>>>" + Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE + "<<<<");
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug to see if this 0 comes from `int total = 0;` because cursor does not return any row, or it does return 1 row with the value 0 as average? One other thing: you don't need all the order by part, you don't want to fetch rows in a particular order but a single value

Comment: Yes I have debugged and int total is indeed returning 0.  I have added a screen shot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql statement is a CREATE statement and not a query to fetch rows. So change it:

```
"SELECT AVG(" + Game.COLUMN_SCORE + ") FROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " = '" + seriesId + "'"
```

You might also need to change: `total = cursor.getInt(0);`  
I'm not sure if the average value which will be produced will be rounded to int.  
 Better use `getDouble` or `getString` and then parse to `int`

Comment: I changed the CREATE to a SELECT and I am now getting near  "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AVERAGE_SCORE AS SELECT AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) FROM game WHERE leagueId = '1' AND bowlerId = '1' AND seriesId = '1'

Comment: Delete `SELECT AVERAGE_SCORE AS` or copy and paste my statement

Comment: I noticed this right after I posted I have removed it and I am getting Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COLUMN_SCORE (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AVG(COLUMN_SCORE) FROM game WHERE leagueId = '1' AND bowlerId = '1' AND seriesId = '1'

Comment: what is the name of the column you want the average of?

Comment: it is Game.COLUMN_SCORE, I tried putting this in but it still does not find the column,

Comment: I will change the statement in a while

Comment: Copy the new statement

Comment: Why the plus signs around the column name?

Comment: Just like the other column names Game.COLUMN_SCORE is a string constant that has to be inserted in the whole sql statement. You know the real value of Game.COLUMN_SCORE which is the column name, I don't.

Comment: Using **" + Game.COLUMN_SCORE + "** worked, thank you very much for all of your help with this.

Comment: I realize this should probably be a new question, but since I am inserting this into the method, I am posting it here in hopes that you will be able to provide some feedback.  

I am inserting `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE,series.getAverage());
        Log.d("GET AVERAGE FROM SQL","Average = >>>>" + Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE + "<<<<");` into the method to write the average into the Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE field.   It seems that  cannot find symbol variable series.

Comment: Is there a column in the table you want to insert the value with name Series.COLUMN_SERIES_AVERAGE?

Comment: Yes there is a column with this name.

Comment: Is it series.getAverage() or Series.getAverage()?

Comment: or getSeriesAverage(..)?

Comment: .public String getAverage() { return average; }

Comment: The name of the class in which these 2 belong is series or Series?

Comment: The class is Series

Comment: if it's a ststic class then use Series.getAverage()

Comment: I have tried using Series.getAverage() but it comes back with **error: non-static method getAverage() cannot be referenced from a static context**  which is why I am trying to use series.getAverage()

Comment: I guess you should post the class

Comment: I have posted the Series Class and the updated method above.

Comment: This is not a static class and I don't know how it retrieves the average. But if you want to use its `getAverage()` method you must 1st create an instance of Series class: `Series series = Series(...);` and then get the average by `series.getAverage();`